# "work with" X or "work at" X, which is better?

Tags: at-with

Context: We are planning to run promotional campaign for hiring engineering talent, and thinking which one these promotional sentences are more correct/connecting or simply better?

**Sentence 1**

20 Reasons to work ***at*** X.

**Sentence 2**

20 Reasons to work ***with*** X.

**Sentence 3**

20 Reasons to work ***for*** X.

Which of the above sentence is more promising and correct for our campaign or website?